# WHERE Clause SAME ID different TABLES vs JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

I read several postings but couldn't find one addressing the issue. IN a T-SQL query I'm to do the following:

> list the (employee last name, project number, assigned job from the
>   (Employee AND Assignment tables) -- where the employee table
>   –(employee number) is equal to the assignment table (employee number).

Does this require an inner join, or can it be done with `WHERE` clause?

I tried the following but got back ambiguous errors:

```
SELECT  
    EMP_LNAME, PROJECT_NUM, ASSIGN_JOB
FROM 
    ASSIGNMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE 
    EMP_ID = EMP_ID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got an ambiguous error because you need to alias your tables. But to answer your question, your current query is the old style of doing a join and will work the same. I prefer the newer style `inner join` because it is more easily readable, imo.

```
SELECT e.EMP_LNAME, a.PROJECT_NUM, a.ASSIGN_JOB 
FROM ASSIGNMENT a,EMPLOYEE e 
WHERE a.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
```

effectively the same as:

```
SELECT e.EMP_LNAME, a.PROJECT_NUM, a.ASSIGN_JOB 
FROM ASSIGNMENT a
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON a.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID
```